# JSON Parsing with JAX-RS

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

I am building an REST API with JAX-RS. I have POST that consumes an JSON element:

The element is a class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class EventData{
   public long start;
   public long end;
   public Collection<Person> persons;
}
```

I have an method like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response transactionRequest(EventData insert){
....}
```

if I post a JSON String of an `EventData` it works fine, but if I switch to:

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response transactionRequest(ArrayList<EventData> insert){
....}
```

and send an JSON String like this `"{eventData:[{start:x,end:y,persons:[....]}]"` it will build the `ArrayList` and its `EventData` objects, but the `EventData` object variables are `null`.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a JSON array consisting of JSON objects representing your `EventData` class.

The sample you've given isn't such a JSON array, but a JSON object with a single property named 'eventData' containing an JSON array.

Try something like this (based on your `EventData` class):

```
[
  { "start":1, "end":2, "persons":[] },
  { "start":3, "end":4, "persons":[] }
]
```

Notice that there is no mention of your `EventData` class, because JSON has no concept of named types -- it's just objects and arrays of objects; only the properties of objects have names.

Comment: com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonFormatException: Colon expected instead of "]"

Comment: The JSON in my answer is a very rough sample, I suggest using the output from a JAX-RS method that returns List<EventData> with some dummy items. I'll write some valid JSON given your `EventData` class in a minute :)

Comment: com.sun.jersey.json.impl.reader.JsonFormatException: Colon expected instead of ","

Comment: Mmh, how are you sending the JSON to your JAX-RS service? This looks like something gets lost on the way.

Comment: yes, hi have an android application that makes a post of a JSON to the JAX-RS service.....if it is an single EventData object in the POST ist works well...

Comment: well hi will make a POST of a JSON String and then an manual parsing to Java Object....at least it will work well

Comment: Could you try sending your JSON to a method with a String parameter instead and either via println or debugger get that string and add it to your question? I suspect that JSON string is not what we both expect. I'll have a look later :)

Comment: the String that it receives is something like; {"eventData":[
  { "start":1, "end":2, "persons":[] },
  { "start":3, "end":4, "persons":[] }
]}  but hi have tried all the ways and don't work... it seems that it doesn't work well with list's....

Comment: You're still sending a JSON object with a single property named `eventData`. Don't do that! Just send an array of JSON objects like the sample in my answer. There must not be any `eventData` in the JSON your JAX-RS class received.

Comment: I might be able to help you further if you post the code that you use to construct and send the JSON in your Android app.